# The Planetary Light Curve

Tags: gravity, visible-light, elements

I know that light can be affected by gravity. But what if there was a planet where if you shone a light in a direction and it could hit your back. I'm talking about a planet where light is bent around the diameter of the planet and back to the starting point. But I am not incredibly good at math so I need help.

The planet must be made of Osmium. Although that is the logical material anyway because I want this planet to be as small as possible without being compressed and Osmium is the densest naturally occurring element *(assuming it won't compresses itself under it's own gravity for some random reason)*. And it must be natural because I want this to be possible. So using this information I wanted to know the diameter of this planet for light to bend all the way around it and I would like to know the gravity of this object.

(I'm not sure if this is your field but astrophysics told me to come here.)

Comment: How are you going to stop this ball of osmium from compressing itself due to gravity? But anyway, if we do a naive calculation using the formula from Chris's answer and a density of $22590 kg/m^3$, ignoring gravitational collapse, the radius is a little over 68.875 million kilometres. And using simple Newtonian mechanics the surface gravity would be about 44340 times that of Earth. Of course, both of these numbers are nonsense.

Comment: @PM2Ring And some 100,000 times the mass of the heaviest known star in the universe ;)

Comment: @Chris That sounds right. I get roughly 15.5 million solar masses. And obtaining that much osmium may prove to be a little difficult. Based on its abundance in our solar system, I think you'd need all the osmium from something like 10000 galaxies, give or take an order of magnitude. :)

Answer (score 4):

You can get a photon to orbit around a black hole, at $\frac{3}{2}$ the Schwarzschild radius. Anything dense enough to get photons orbiting it won't be a planet anymore, it'll be a black hole or maybe a neutron star.

Comment: Is this a comment or an answer.

Comment: This is an answer.

Answer (score -2):

"How are you going to stop this ball of osmium from compressing itself due to gravity? But anyway, if we do a naive calculation using the formula from Chris's answer and a density of $22590\frac{kg}{m^3}$, ignoring gravitational collapse, the radius is a little over 68.875 million kilometres. And using simple Newtonian mechanics the surface gravity would be about 44340 times that of Earth. Of course, both of these numbers are nonsense." ***Thank you PM 2Ring as this is his answer but he did not post it in the answer section.***

Comment: This will be my answer for now but if anyone does want to recommend or check this then it is welcome.